# can't install model_selection on python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7, module, scikit-learn, grid-search

I try to run this line:

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

but I get an ImportError (i.e. No module named model_selection)  although I have installed sklearn and I can import other packages. here is my python version :

2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

is there a way to use "sklearn.model_selection" on my current version?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. the 0.18 sklearn has seen a number of updates. you may update your sklearn by typing "conda update scikit-learn" in your windows command line.

If it still didn't code you might want to update your conda/Anaconda as well:

"conda update conda" and "conda update Anaconda"